# Golang signing with ecdsa and Private Key from a SHA224 digest

Tags: cryptography, go, ecdsa

I need to sign a message for submission to a remote service (over a websocket). To do this, I need to structure a private key based on an integer (my user id) and a passphrase (a base64 encoded string)., hashed using SHA224. I'm using golang, and crypto/ecdsa for this with accompanying packages for byte encoding etc.

Here's the documentation I have:

> Signatures use an Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)
>   encoded message containing: user ID, Server Nonce, Client Node and
>   Private key. Private keys are generated hashing your user ID and your
>   password with SHA224.

Here's my func:

```
func NewKey(userId int64, pass string) (prKey ecdsa.PrivateKey) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, userId)
    passArr := []byte(pass)

    sha := sha256.New224()
    sha.Write(buf.Bytes())
    sha.Write(passArr)
    sum := sha.Sum(nil)

    var in int64
    reader := bytes.NewReader(sum)
    err := binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &in)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    prKey.D = big.NewInt(in)
    prKey.PublicKey.Curve = elliptic.P224()
    return prKey
}
```

My intent with this func is that it:

1. Hashes the userId and pass correctly in a `[]byte` using SHA224.
2. Reads that into an `int64` which is then used as the private key
3. Constructs an instance of `ecdsa.PrivateKey` and corresponding `ecdsa.PublicKey` correctly
4. Returns said key for use in `ecdsa.Sign()` function calls

I then sign another message which consists of a userId (integer), and two nonces.

Here's how I sign my message:

```
key := NewKey(userId, pass) // the above func
msg := sha256.New224().Sum([]byte(userId + srNonce + clNonce))
r, s, err := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, &key, msg)
sig := []string{enc(r.String()), enc(s.String())}
```

Questions:

1. Is my `NewKey` func correct?
2. The `r` and `s` components are very large - presumably because I'm using `int64`. Could this be an issue?
3. Is the line `sha256.New224().Sum([]byte(userId + pass))` "correct" for hasing those two items?
4. How can I create my private key correctly (assuming it's wrong) and subsequently sign the message?

I'm very new to ECDSA and have basic crypto knowledge in general.

Comment: (1) You probably don't want `binary.PutUvarint`, but instead binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64` (or `BigEndian` if appropriate).  (2) can you provide a link that describes the protocol you're trying to implement?  Without that, it is difficult to say what is wrong.

Comment: I'll replace that PutUvarint call - thank you. Updated with the little documentation I have.

Comment: Actually I'm using `PutVarint` now as it's a signed 64bit integer.

Comment: The Varint encoding from `encoding/binary` is a variable length encoding that comes from the Protocol Buffers specification.  If you want to simply encode the integer to 8 bytes, then you don't want `PutVarint`.

Comment: Use what I mentioned in my first comment: `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64` or `binary.BigEndian.PutUint64`.  If you have a signed integer, you'll need to cast it to the unsigned variant first.

Comment: Found a way of using `Write` based on the examples on encoding/binary documentation. Post updated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"The r and s components are very large... "* - `r` and `s` will be the size of the secp-224 field (not the hash). It matters if you use a different hash, like SHA-1 or SHA-512. In your case both `r` and `s` will be 32-bytes. By the way, `secp-224` is very unusual. Nearly 99% of what is on the web uses secp-256. The number comes from an academic survey of the Alexa Top 1M, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own questions:

> Is my NewKey func correct?

No.

> The r and s components are very large - presumably because I'm using int64. Could this be an issue?

They should be large.

> Is the line sha256.New224().Sum([]byte(userId + pass)) "correct" for hashing those two items?

It's correct insofar as I'm passing it a `[]byte`.

> How can I create my private key correctly (assuming it's wrong) and
>   subsequently sign the message?

The key requires a `big.Int`, so using the following should suffice assuming the hash is correct:

```
key := new(big.Int).SetBytes(sum)
```